# django manipulate session(insert,update,...)

Tags: python, django, session, cart, django-sessions

i want to add product's ref_id in cart(i use django session and ajax)
you look at the code that I wrote and tell me why always the `"cart not exist"` is displayed
to solve the problem what I do?

```
class add_to_cart(View):
    def post(self,request):
        ref_id = request.POST.get('ref_id',None)
        if(ref_id):
            print("request.session={}".format(request.session))
            # flag = request.session.get('cart',None)
            if 'cart' not in request.session:
                print("cart not exist")
                request.session['cart'] = {ref_id:1}
            else:
                print("cart exist")
                if ref_id in request.session['cart']:
                    print("ref_id exist in cart")
                else:
                    print("ref_id not exist in cart")
        else:
            print("ref_id has not sent")
```

In the meantime, I'm sure that I've written code Ajax is correct

Comment: Don't know anything about manipulating sessions but have you tried adding the line `print(request.session)` just before `if 'cart' not in request.session` to see what is going on? Maybe you need to do `if cart not in str(request.session)`? These are both long shots though.

Comment: i try 'if cart not in str(request.session)' but displayed '"cart not exist"' again

Comment: I've got the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution
 Should after every each change the session use:

```
request.session.save()
```

I thank everyone for their help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `request.session.modified = True` after initiating the cart.
You should notify Django that the session has been changed every time you interfere with it.

Comment: If you print the session after the `request.session.modified = True` is there 'cart' in the output?